# How to add rename annotation?

Tags: visual-studio, annotations, refactoring, rename, roslyn

I'm writing custom *CodeRefactoringProvider*. My refactoring generates some new variables. I want user to rename these generated variables. How can I add rename annotations like ones used in "Extract method" refactoring?

Namespace *Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Rename* exposes only static class *Renamer*, but it renames symbols without any highlighting and user interaction, so it's not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found solution. The required annotations is **Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CodeActions.RenameAnnotation**

This is how to create new variable token:

```cs
SyntaxToken newVarToken = SyntaxFactory.VerbatimIdentifier(
    default(SyntaxTriviaList), 
    "newVar1", "newVar2", 
    default(SyntaxTriviaList))
    .WithAdditionalAnnotations(RenameAnnotation.Create());
```

or with VariableDeclarator:

```cs
var declarator = SyntaxFactory.VariableDeclarator("newVar1");
declarator = declarator.ReplaceToken(
    declarator.Identifier,
    declarator.Identifier.WithAdditionalAnnotations(RenameAnnotation.Create()));
```